# Why does streaming query not write any data to HDFS?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming with Spark 2.3.1 and below is my code:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
.builder
.appName("xxx")
.config("spark.serializer", 
  "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
.config("spark.rpc.netty.dispatcher.numThreads", "2")
.config("spark.shuffle.compress", "true")
.config("spark.rdd.compress", "true")
.config("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", "true")
.config("spark.io.compression.codec", "snappy")
.config("spark.broadcast.compress", "true")
.config("spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession", "true")
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
.config("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable","true")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()

val rawStreamDF = sparkSession
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", <value>)
.option("subscribe", <value>)
.option("key.serializer", <value>)
.option("value.serializer", <value>)
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.option("auto.offset.reset",earliest)
.option("group.id",  <value>)
.option("fetchOffset.numRetries", 3)
.option("fetchOffset.retryIntervalMs", 10)
.option("IncludeTimestamp", true)
.option("enable.auto.commit",  <value>)
.option("security.protocol",  <value>)
.option("ssl.keystore.location",  <value>)
.option("ssl.keystore.password",  <value>)
.option("ssl.truststore.location",  <value>)
.option("ssl.truststore.password",  <value>)
.load()
.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
.as[(String, String)]
```

I'm trying to write the data to a file in the hdfs_path:

```
val query = rawStreamDF
  .writeStream
  .format("json")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("path", "STREAM_DATA_PATH")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpointPath")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
  .outputMode("append")
  .start

Logger.log.info("Status:"+query.status)
print("Streaming Status1:"+query.status)

query.awaitTermination(450)
```

But, I'm getting `query.status` value as below:

```
Status:{ "message" : "Initializing sources", "isDataAvailable" : false, "isTriggerActive" : false }
```

Could you let me know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> But, I'm getting query.status value as below.
>
> ```
> Status:{ "message" : "Initializing sources", "isDataAvailable" :false, "isTriggerActive" : false }
> ```
>
> Could you let me know where I'm going wrong?

All seems fine. The streaming engine of Spark Structured Streaming didn't seem to start the query yet, but just mark it as to be started on a separate thread.

If you created a separate thread for monitoring the structured query, you'd notice the status would change right after processing the very first batch.

Consult the official documentation in [Structured Streaming Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html).